# HighStock displays inaccurate Date Range

Tags: highcharts

This is the image before Drilling Down

```
http://imgur.com/qCSplBR
```

Image after drilling down

```
http://imgur.com/BbAbU7k
```

The date seems to be inaccurate on the tool tip before drilling down.

Comment: Am I the only one who can't open/load your images...

Comment: Well the image url is below indented as code

Comment: Please replicate your example as live demo, on jsfiddle.net.